# Add red star in swagger schema for custom validation attributes

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

I use ASP.NET Core web api, when I use `[Required]` attribute for my view model properties, swagger will show a red star in schema like below

```
public class InsertCircularFrm
{
    [Required]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Now i have a custom validation attribute for prevent entering empty guid:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class GuidNotEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value is Guid guidValue)
        {
            if (guidValue == Guid.Empty)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage ?? $"{validationContext.DisplayName} is required");
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

```
public class InsertCircularFrm
{
    [GuidNotEmpty]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

But now it doesn't show red star in schema when I use my custom validation attribute `GuidNotEmpty`

[image]

Guid is value type and because of that if client doesn't send value for that, it gives defalut value and required attribute doesn't work for that, now with above codes i check for emtpy guid, but the main question is how can I config swagger to show red star for my custom validation attribute in swagger ui ?

Comment: Can you not just use both attributes? Like [Required, GuidNotEmpty]

Comment: @tomredfern yes I can, but is there any solution to do that with my custom validation attribute ?

Comment: What I mean is: if you use both attributes then do you get the red star? If so then that is the solution, unless I'm missing something?